# Create Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a countdown Timer in React Js in which i will user Start(To start the countdown), Stop(To stop the countdown) and reset (to reset the timer) as in the picture exemple.[image: Wanted Timer]

As i beginner developper in React JS and in javascript globally, i started by testing the button.After that i created a function "secondPass" to calculate the remaining time and after that displaying it.The "countDown" variable is for stopping the "setinterval" after that with "clearInterval(countDown)".

The problem is that i get an error msg in the "codesandbox" plateform as in the picture.If someone can explain my error and if not to much asked help me to write a very simple code to achieve my project.

: [image: Error msg]

Here the React code:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 90
    };
  }

  var seconds = 1200, // Number Of Seconds

  countDown = setInterval(function() {
    secondPass();
  }, 1000);

  function secondPass() {

  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),  // To Determine The Minutes 

  var remSeconds = seconds % 60;   // To Determine The Seconds

}

  resetTime() {
    this.setState({ timer: 0 });
  }
  render() {
    const { timer } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{timer}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetTime()}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is countdown? You need to initialise it with a keyword.
Try putting let before countDown = ...

Comment: You have some syntax errors. Basically, you can't define variables (`seconds`) and methods the way you do, it's wrong syntax. You may find this link useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: try without the `function` keyword when defining the `secondPass()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to use function keyword when declaring functions in a class for secondPass function. It’s the new ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `secondPass` is a member function defined in the body of the `Timer` class. In JS, you do not need the `function` before it, declare it just like render: change `function secondPass` to `secondPass`

Answer (score 1):

remove the `function` keyword for `secondPass` function. you don't need function keyword for function if you are declaring it inside a class.

make it like,

```
export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 90
    };
  }

  var seconds = 1200, // Number Of Seconds

  countDown = setInterval(function() {
    secondPass();
  }, 1000);

  secondPass() {

    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),  // To Determine The Minutes 

    var remSeconds = seconds % 60;   // To Determine The Seconds

  }

  resetTime() {
    this.setState({ timer: 0 });
  }
  render() {
    const { timer } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{timer}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetTime()}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```